# fetching json data and display using jquery in Python

Tags: jquery, python, django, json, django-views

json file which is having some data.Using jQuery i need to display into page.

.json file is

```
{
"p1":{
      "item1":"apple",
      "item2":"orange",
      "item3":"banana",
      },
"p2":{
      "item1":"water",
      "item2":"milk",
      "item3":"alcohol",
     }
}
```

my templates is

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <ul></ul>
    <button></button>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.9.1,min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

myscript.js file is

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("item.json",function(obj){
       $.each(obj,function(key,value){
          $("ul").append("<li>+value.item1+"</li>");
          $("ul").append("<li>+value.item2+"</li>");
          $("ul").append("<li>+value.item3+"</li>");
       });
    });
});
```

Json data gets loaded in the page while press the "getjson" button in the page but page is getting refresh no daat gets loaded.How to do that,i think some error inthe above code or whether i need to write any function in views.py using python.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? You need to pass in the url of your django server to the `$.getJSON()` function.

Comment: nothing i am getting simply the page gets refresh while pressing the button

Comment: Where is the `item.json` file stored at? Is it being served by your django server?

Comment: button click must be `$("#button").click(function(){`, forgot the `#` and also put the correct path of the json file

Comment: item.json was in my app folder the location is /fixtures/item.json

Comment: sorry i am not getting your idea,explain brief please

Comment: you have syntax errors in the string concatenation...missing quotes. Also is more efficient to make one string and do one append, rather than append every element

Comment: yes i corrected already but it is not displaying the json value

Comment: I need to import anything in the .js file.My full myscript.js file looks like in the above so is it ok or to add any tags in that

Comment: also have trailing commas in objects...will break in some browsers, notably IE

Comment: if page is reloading, sounds like button is in a form and either need to prevent browser default submit in click handler or change button to `type="button"`

Comment: Also, why is your <body> enclosed within <head> in the html??

Answer (score 1):

First of, you should consider using the JQuery on-ready function (http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

```
$(function() {
   ...
});
```

This way your code is executed once all the html is loaded and you dont run into problems, because you switch the order of the `<script>`-Tag (For example into the head-section) and your button is suddenly not found.

Second, as Catherine mentioned in the Comments, you should give your button an id or class, to identify it. It should also work without that, but i just checked and that doesnt seem to work. Then you can use the CSS-Selector for the id `$("#MyButton")`

```
<button id="MyButton">My Button</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#MyButton").click(function() { 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Next you have the JSON-Part. `$.getJSON(url, data, success)`. So first you will need the url to the json-file. How to get the url depends on where your file is. If it is a view, include the link to the view (`{% url "project.app.views.get_json" %}` for example) or the static file (`{{STATIC_URL}}/js/data/file.json` for example). If the file is in your fixtures-dir, than you have to create a view, that loads that file and returns the content as a Response, or copy the file to one of the static-folders, depending on what you want. Expecting Javascript (Client-Side) to find a file on your Server (Server-side) wont work, without some part on the server providing the file. (For similar purposes, i have a small decorator, which renders the return-value - python-dict, array, values - of a view as json and creates an appropriate HttpResponse-Object)

The `data` parameter may be skipped, so the last parameter is the success-callback:

```
<button id="MyButton">My Button</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#MyButton").click(function() { 
            $.getJSON("your url here", function(data) {
                console.log(data); #Print the data to console
            }).fail(function() {
                console.log("Something went wrong with the request!");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

From there you should be able to access the data. For more callbacks like `fail()` see the API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
Note, that in your snippet for adding the data to the ul you have an error with the quotes, and you could also chain the calls to append, to avoid looking up the same tag over and over again:

```
$("#myList")
    .append("<li>" + value.item1 + "</li>")
    .append("<li>" + value.item2 + "</li>")
    .append("<li>" + value.item3 + "</li>");
```